# How to remove from list if list based on condition

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of objects like this:

```
MyObject {

   Date date;
   int value;
}
```

I want to iterate the list and only keeps the objects where the dates differ.  If there are two objects with the same date then I want to keep the object with the bigger value.  Can this be achieved by using streams and predicates somehow?

Comment: This sounds like you really want an associative array (dictionary, mapping) that maps from the date to the corresponding largest value.

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Map` and `Map.merge()` instread of `Stream`.

```
record MyObject(Date date, int value) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> list = List.of(
        new MyObject(new Date(0), 0),
        new MyObject(new Date(0), 1),
        new MyObject(new Date(1000), 2));

    Map<Date, MyObject> map = new LinkedashMap<>();
    for (MyObject e : list)
        map.merge(e.date(), e, (a, b) -> a.value() > b.value() ? a : b);
    list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

    for (MyObject e : list)
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

output:

```
MyObject[date=Thu Jan 01 09:00:00 JST 1970, value=1]
MyObject[date=Thu Jan 01 09:00:01 JST 1970, value=2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `stream` to filter distinct elements:

```
public class MyObject {
    
    private final LocalDate date;
    
    private final int value;
    
    public MyObject(LocalDate date, int value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public final LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    
    public final int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[date=" + date + ", value=" + value +"]";
    }
}
```

To get distinct elements you can do:

```
public static Collection<MyObject> getDistinct(List<MyObject> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getDate, 
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(MyObject::getValue)), 
                            Optional::get)))
            .values();
}
```

Then:

```
List<MyObject> list = List.of(new MyObject(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1), 1),
            new MyObject(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1), 2),
            new MyObject(LocalDate.of(2022, 2, 2), 2));
    
Collection<MyObject> distinct = getDistinct(list);
    
distinct.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[date=2022-02-02, value=2]
[date=2021-01-01, value=2]
```

**Note:** I would use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`